# How can i install missing modules of Python?

Tags: python-3.x

First of all I have to admit that I'm a starter. I know there are similar topics like mine. But I couldn't find the proper answer.
I was installing python in my Ubuntu. Downloaded the ‘Python-3.5.1.tar.xz’. And I used the cd command to access this file's path. After that, entered './configure' then 'make'.
It gave me this message:

> Python build finished successfully!
>   The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
>   _bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel
>   _dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma
>   _sqlite3              _ssl
>   To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Now, how can I install those specific modules ? Thank you.

Comment: I think you're going the hard way. Can't you get a pre-built distribution of python 3.5 ?

Comment: Just use  `apt-get install python3 python3-dev python3-setuptools`

Comment: @dmitryro What does this command install ?

Comment: This will install python3 through package management, which will guarantee you don't have any broken dependencies and won't have to provide options in `./configure` when you build it from source. This is the easy way to install. There's no point of building from source unless you need some  unique configuration (which is not the case).

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre i just followed the instructions of a website. Should I give up what I am dealing with ? Looks like I'm far away from that point. What's your suggest ?

Comment: @dmitryro thank you a lot. I'll try your suggest and gonna inform you

Comment: @JohnWarren: I was just telling you what to avoid. But dmityro seems to tell you what to do to get a package on Linux (I can't help further: I run windows :))

Comment: @JohnWarren You're welcome. Try running `apt-get update` prior running `apt-get install python3` to make sure all the repositories are up to date.

Comment: @dmitryro I gave the make command again after getting setup tools. But it said the same thing; Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _ssl                                     
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.

Comment: @dmitryro should i ignore ?

Comment: Once you've installed python3 you don't need to run `make` and `sudo make isntall` - for the additional packages needed run `apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` and `apt-get install libbz2-dev`. Once this is done you should be able to run python3 on your scripts.

Comment: @dmitryro thank you. Have a nice day.